# How to do a Cube Map Texturing on a Sphere?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, mapping, textures

I am working in QT with OpenGL, and I have a sphere in the project. What I need is to do a Cube Map Texturing on the sphere.

Does anybody have any material or anything that can help me to do this? I am not finding anything like this on the internet that can help me :(. Please if you have anything in that direction, ti would be really helpfull

The Sphere is created by code, by creating triangles and then shading.

Comment: you could try using MatCap instead : )

Comment: thanks man, your answer helped me a lot now after 6 years

Answer (score 0):

For a point `p` on the surface of a sphere centered at `c`, use `normalised(p - c)` as the texture coordinate of `p`.

Conceptually, imagine the cubemap texture centered at the sphere's center. Mapping the texture to a point on the sphere corresponds to casting a ray from the center of the sphere through the surface point, and using the texel hit by that ray. That's precisely what you'll get by using the `c->p` vector (a.k.a. `p - c`) as the cubemap texture coordinate.

Comment: Thnx for you answer, but I really need the code of this what you are saying :( I am new in QT and OpenGL

Comment: @user3774470 You haven't shown any of your code, I have followed suit. Not to mention the fact that my answer certainly qualifies as "anyhting in that direction." SO is not for "gimme teh codez" questions. Try implementing it yourself, consult an online tutorial or two, and if you're still stuck, edit your question to include the code you've tried in a [concise, clearly-formatted shape](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), asking for the specific thing you're stuck with.